# Why DefaultMessageListenerContainer thows warning

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have specified the wrong response queue name but the exception is not getting raised instead a warning is getting written in log.I want to know why defaultmessagelistenercontainer thows warning and how to catch that warning.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: public class MQReceiver  implements javax.jms.MessageListener {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 }
 @Override
 public void onMessage(Message message) {
  if(message instanceof TextMessage){
  try{
   System.out.println("Inside on message method"); 
   System.out.println(((TextMessage)message).getText()); 
   }catch(JMSException ex){   
    System.out.println("Hello in exception catch block");
    
   } } } }

Comment: <bean id="jmsReciever" class="com.prog.messaging.MQReceiver">
    </bean>
  
 <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
 <property name="messageListener" ref="jmsReciever" />
 <property name="connectionFactory" ref ="jmsFactory" />
 <property name="Destination" ref="receiverQueue" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL">
<value>tcp://Toshiba:61616</value>
</property>
  
When a mq exception is logged it is getting as warning in log.I want to log that as exception

Comment: I know it might be the default implementation of listener but is there anyway to handle it through log4j.xml to flag it as error rather than warning

Comment: you're going to want to include the code snippets in the question section (you can edit the original question) and you'll want to have it formatted (indentation per Java standards) for readability. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting